# Standalone version of class AnnotationLiteral?

Tags: java, annotations, cdi

The CDI (Context Dependency Injection) Framework contains the awesome class [`javax.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral.html) that makes it very easy to create an instance of an Annotation (especaly useful for tests).

I want to use that util class in my own library. But because my library has noting to do with CDI, I do not want to have all the other CDI stuff.
Fortunately AnnotationLiteral does not use any other classes than standard java classes, so this should be possible in general.

Up to now the smallest Library that contains AnnotationLiteral is the official [CDI-API](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
   <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But even if I cut off all the dependencies (by maven exclude), the jar will contain a lot of other CDI-API and -SPI stuff.

So my question is: Is there already some (more or less official) (maven) library that contains only the `util.AnnotationLiteral` Class, or at least not so much other stuff?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you comply with the license, you could copy the [source](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22javax.enterprise%22%20AND%20a%3a%22cdi-api%22) into your project.

If that is possible, I would retain the package name incase CDI eventually does become a project dependency. The only reason I would change the package is if you decide to modify the source, which of course doesn't mean you can remove the license.

Answer (score 1):

An Apache licensed version of `AnnotationLiteral` can be found in the [geronimo api](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/geronimo/specs/trunk/geronimo-jcdi_1.0_spec/src/main/java/javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral.java). It does not look like it has any dependencies to other parts of CDI. If you don't need the equals and hashCode implementation it provides in your tests you could even directly implement an annotation interface. This is not really good style but definitely possible. CDI needs the additional equals and hashCode implementation for its Qualifier logic. Here is an example using the jsf `ManagedBean` annotation:

```
public static ManagedBean test = new ManagedBean() {
    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean eager() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return ManagedBean.class;
    }  
};
```

Comment: I was looking for the correct approach to instantiate an annotation class and this is the perfect answer for me. This also gives a correct answer to the original question.