# Passing additional information about tests from JUnit Runner to RunListener

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit-runner

I'm implementing a custom JUnit Runner and would like to add additional reporting capabilities to it. I'd also like to reuse as much existing JUnit infrastructure as possible, so implementing a `RunListener` sounded like a good idea. Methods of `RunListener` either take a `Description` or a `Failure`, both with no obvious way to add additional information about the testcases.

`Description` is effectively final because it has no public constructor, so overriding it is not possible. There is a private `uniqueId` field that could be misused via reflection but that would be really hacky.

A slightly less hacky variant might be to define annotations for all the information I need and attach implementations of this annotation to the `Description`. Has anyone done something like this or is there a recommended way how this could be handled?

Here is an example of what I'm currently trying:

```
public @interface StepMetadata {
    int lineNumber();
    String keyword();
    String title();
}

public class StepMetadataImpl implements StepMetadata {
    private final int lineNumber;
    private final String keyword;
    private final String title;

    // constructor and accessor methods

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return StepMetadata.class;
    }
}


// inside the Runner
Description.createTestDescription(className, stepTitle, new StepMetadataImpl(...))

// inside the RunListener
StepMetadata step = description.getAnnotation(StepMetadata.class)
```

Related question, are there any downsides to writing implementations of annotation interfaces?

Comment: [The documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Description.html#createTestDescription%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.annotation.Annotation...%29) certainly suggests annotations are for this purpose: "*annotations - meta-data about the test, for downstream interpreters*". I'm a little unclear about your actual question though - have you tried this and failed? Are you unsure if this is the right approach?

Comment: @Duncan: Thanks, I'm unsure if this is the right approach if my underlying tests are not actual java methods and I have to create the annotations myself. I have not come across much code that uses this little-known feature. And to do it correctly seems a little bit more complicated, now that I found this previous answer about `AnnotationLiteral`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7084532/139595